# Updating Answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it a good idea to revisit and update answers after a while if new information has come to light?  I'm thinking of a couple of answers I've given a while back, where there's been quite a bit of development in the field (eg, web application scanners).

On the one hand it seems somehow wrong to be substantially changing an answer after people have voted on it and the answer has been accepted, on the other hand it seems like a good idea to refresh answers to ensure that they're still current, especially if they're ones that receive quite a bit of traffic.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, please update your answers if new information is relevant (especially if old information is irrelevant). The people visiting the site today will be looking for - and thus expecting to see, vote and comment on - relevant information to whatever problem they have today, not the problem someone had a couple of months back. I have been back over a few of my answers and edited revisions in over time.

Comment: I agree. On the other hand, if there is a question that is really out of date, you can also ask a new question to get more info... Though the better questions/answers shouldnt be limited to a specific point in time...

Comment: @AviD I’ve experienced a couple of situations over at Stack Overflow where there were questions flagged as duplicated of older questions but the more recent questions had better answers. So it’s definitely a good idea to ask a question again if the answers to an older question might be out of date or not satisfying enough.